# Fetching user input from input field into js table that creates table cells via for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I've been attempting to fetch user input value from input fields to later on set it into a summary table that creates cells using javascript but can't seem to get it to work.

Following is my code:

```
function summonTable(f) {
    var sLoc = f.countryf.value();
    var eLoc = f.countryt.value();
    var sDate = f.sdate.value();
    var eDate = f.edate.value();

    var div = document.getElementById("summary");

    var magicTable = document.getElementById('summaryTable').querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = sDate;
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = sLoc;


            //To state which row and column this cell goes to.
            row.appendChild(th);
            div.appendChild(magicTable);
        });
```

The function summonTable will take in the arguement form f that contains the input fields, I've tried basic textboxes, checkboxes, radios, but all to no avail. The variables sLoc, eLoc are basically texts for countries and sDate, eDate are supposed to be dates.

Comment: you forgot to append row to the table element--magicTable.appendChild(row);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function summonTable(f) {
    var sLoc = f.countryf.value();
    var eLoc = f.countryt.value();
    var sDate = f.sdate.value();
    var eDate = f.edate.value();

    var div = document.getElementById("summary");
// to get the last row of the table
    var magicTable = document.getElementById('summaryTable').querySelectorAll('tbody tr:last-child'),
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = sDate;
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = sLoc;


            //To state which row and column this cell goes to.
            row.appendChild(th);
            magicTable.after(row); //To add the row after the last row
            div.appendChild(magicTable);
        });
```